Azure B2C sign-in flow and API Connector Blocking Response
I’m trying to implement API Connector for run custom logic inside Azure B2C sign-in process. The logic should be that when some implemented conditions are met – user is able to successfully log into application. However, when they are not met – sign-in process should be stopped, and proper information should be presented inside B2C login window.
For this scenario – I’ve tried to return blocking response using documentation from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow#example-of-a-blocking-response. However, it does not work for my flow. The code is successfully executed but the sign-in process is not canceled, and no information is presented for the end user.  My code returning blocking response looks like below:
return GetB2cApiConnectorResponse("ShowBlockPage", result.ErrorMessage, 200);

and
private IActionResult GetB2cApiConnectorResponse(string action, string userMessage, int statusCode)
        {
            var responseProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "version", "1.0.0" },
                { "action", action },
                { "userMessage", userMessage }
            };
            if (statusCode != 200)
            {
                responseProperties["status"] = statusCode.ToString();
            }
            return new JsonResult(responseProperties) { StatusCode = statusCode };
        }

Any ideas?
UPDATE: Ok. I've found our here (Azure ad b2c custom connector "ShowBlockPage" response is not working) that ShowBlockPage works only for sign-up's flows. My questions is then - is it possible at all to return some message from API connector backend and present it to the end-user when B2C sing-in process is failed due to custom conditions?

It is not possible to return a blocking response from an API connector in a sign-in user flow in Azure AD B2C. The "ShowBlockPage" action only works for sign-up user flows. However, you can return a validation-error response from the API connector backend and present it to the end-user when the B2C sign-in process fails due to custom conditions.
